# scheduled job's job action exceeds 4000 characters in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jobs

I have a scheduled job that I am trying to update its `job_action` based on new requirements but the string now exceeds 4000 characters. Is there a way to allow the `job_action` to exceed 4000 characters without problems? Or what's the solution?

Comment: Is there an error?  Please show your code.

Comment: Generally, I'd want anything more than a trivial anonymous block to be a stored procedure just from a maintenance and support standpoint.  I'd really want to move to a stored procedure if my anonymous block was more than 4000 characters long-- that's generally longer than I'd want a single stored procedure let alone a single anonymous block.  Can you move to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

You must have scheduler with `job_type` as  `PLSQL_BLOCK`, which allows 4000 characters in `job_action`.

If you want more than 4000 characters of code to execute in job than create the `procedure` with your code (which is more than 4000 characters) and then you need to alter the scheduler with `job_type` as `STORED_PROCEDURE` and `job_action` as your newly created procedure name.

Something like following(example from oracle docs):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE', -- change needed here in your case
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY', -- change needed here in your case
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

Cheers!!